# Does "Captain Marvel" contain spoilers for "Avengers: Infinity War"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, captain-marvel

I am forced to watch these Marvel Movies in the following order (I have seen every other movie already, only those remain):

1. *Captain Marvel*
2. *Avengers: Infinity War*
3. *Ant-Man & the Wasp*
4. *Avengers: Endgame*

Reasons are limited remaining airing time of *Captain Marvel* at my local theatre and difficulties with overlapping freetime of the people I would like to watch these films together with.

So my question is: Can I safely watch *Captain Marvel* without it spoiling *Infinity War* for me? (Answers please without spoilers!)

I know *Captain Marvel* came out after *Infinity War*, but that it plays some time in the past. But I am afraid of timeskips and other bare spoilery things with regards to *Infinity War*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can watch the movie safely, but I suggest you go to the bathroom and/or take a snack when it comes to the credits, which, without going into details, spoil a major (but known) event of *Infinity War*, and a lesser known (but more of a spoiler) event.

**Hover at your own risk;** the thing is that *Infinity War*...

> served to tease the appearance of Captain Marvel into the MCU, in its post-credits scene. Thus, the scene consists of her being called by someone about to die.

And *Captain Marvel*'s mid-credits scene...

> has her arriving on Earth, asking what happened to the character who called her.

That's the mid-credits scene, however; the post-credits scene of *Captain Marvel* is a funny one which doesn't spoil anything. Actually, it even answers a question you might ask yourself during the movie, if you've seen the first *Avengers* movie.

Comment: Or just leave the theater when the credits start to roll. The post-credits scene is not really worth waiting for.

Comment: @Moyli to each their own, but personally I enjoy staying comfortably in the theater seat, listening to the ending credits music, still being in the movie's ambiance, before I go back to the real world ;) (plus, hey, I paid for the ticket, better make the most out of it :P )

Answer (score 3):

The bulk of the movie does not contain any spoilers for Infinity War that I can think of. However, the during-credits stinger scene does. The post-credits scene does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be all set.

*Captain Marvel*, set in the 1990s does not intersect with *Infinity War*, set in 2018, or *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, also set in 2018.   However, because you are watching this one out of order, **stop at the start of the credits**, because they contain stingers that won't make sense.

After *Ant-Man and the Wasp* and *Infinity War*,

- you can watch the stingers for *Captain Marvel*.
- you can watch the trailers for *Endgame* (and also the [HISHE Endgame trailer](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bwjF3QWCrXA) parody; link is referential- ***don't watch it now***.)

Your sequence will actually help you better understand a stinger in *Infinity War*.

The important thing is that you see all of them before *Endgame*, which you are.